# Why does a failed __repr__ in Maya's python cause the next execution of anything to fail?

Tags: python, maya, repr

As a bit of background, I use the Python in Maya, though it doesn't actually have autosave capabilities, so I wrote a script half a year ago to run in the background and autosave every minute or so.

I was working on something when the unknown error message popped up from the autosave script (first time it's ever happened), and after a bit of debugging I realised it was caused by when `__repr__` had failed in the code I was currently writing. I had a quick google but couldn't find any information on the subject, so I'm wondering if anyone knows the reason why it'll also cause the next command to fail as well?

I also imagine it could do some damage if there's an important script running and someone causes that error (important as in would crash the program if it was stopped), would there be a better way to check for it specifically in the important script than a general `except`?

As an example, here's how I can reproduce it:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        #Do something wrong (in this case format doesn't have enough values)
        return 'TestClass({})'.format()

a = TestClass()

>>> a
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\utils.py", line 393, in _guiResultHook
#     return formatGuiResult(obj)
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel\internal\startup.py", line 74, in myResultCallback
#     return pprint.pformat(obj)
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 60, in pformat
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 119, in pformat
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 137, in _format
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 230, in _repr
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 242, in format
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\python27.zip\pprint.py", line 327, in _safe_repr
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in __repr__
# IndexError: tuple index out of range
# Result:  # 


>>> print 2
# Error: IndexError: file <maya console> line 3: tuple index out of range # 

>>> print 2
2
```

In Maya, instead of the `>>>` way, you just select the bit of code to run and hit enter (in this case I just select and run `a=TestClass()` then `a`), so I've no idea if the problem is also in other interpreters.

Comment: no repro with ipython/ipython3

Comment: Can not reproduce in Python 2.7

Comment: Hmm, in that case it may be more specific to running python within Maya

Comment: It's probably in Maya's override of sys.excepthook:

http://nathanhorne.com/?p=245

Comment: Interesting thought, I tried running the first block of code but it didn't stop that particular problem from happening though :P